# Unable to use Kubuntu supplied Nvidia drivers for MSI GEForce GP108 (GT 1030) card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, xorg

I have a custom-built PC with a Gigabyte B450M H motherboard, Ryzen 5 3600 CPU, 16GB RAM and a GEforce GP108 (GT 1030) GPU. I am running Kubuntu 20.04.2 with / on a 256GB NVME disk and /home on a Seagate 3TB hard disk. The GPU driver is the Nouveau driver running two screens (one connected via the display port and the other on the HDMI port).
All updates are current.
The kernel is the HWE 5.8.0-492104061620-generic #1+mediatree+hauppauge~hwe-Ubuntu (I have a Hauppauge WinTVHD card installed for Mythtv use).

The problem occurs when I install the nvidia-driver-460 meta package through the Driver Manager/Additional Drivers GUI. It seems to complete the install fine with no errors that I've found, and then I reboot.
Once rebooted and logged in okay, it works fine and the nvidia-smi command works to show that the driver is loaded (not got the details at present). When I logout that the logout process starts and then the screens goes black, with no access through the keyboard or mouse. The only way to reboot is to REISUB on the sysrq keys.
One thing is that an SSH session is still connected and I can view the syslog etc. I can't issue a reboot command as that disconnects the session but the system is still locked. It seems that it's the X system or the sddm manager that crashes.
I have put the syslog entry in [pastbin link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mHtPFSqYxM/).

Thing that I have tried without success, in no particular order:

- Changed the PCI express gen level through 1 to 3 in the BIOS.
- Updated the BIOS to the latest on the Gigabyte website.
- Created and used a new user.
- Installed Kubuntu 21.04 running kernel 5.11 and the additional nvidia 460 driver on a spare partition. Same result but syslog
  not available.
- Tried different nvidia drivers as listed in the additional drivers GUI.
- Installed the Mate desktop and lightdm manager. Same result.

Unfortunately I am not experienced enough to know whether the card is possibly faulty or it's a driver issue from reading the syslog entries. I don't have access to Windows to try it on and am not prepared to install it anyway.
One thing that I haven't tried is another kernel, but since I had the same problem with Kubuntu 21.04 I don't think it's that.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up getting a relatively cheap NVIDIA card (GEForce GT 710) and now the nvidia drivers work and logging out happens with no errors.
I presume that I have a faulty GT 1030 card :(